# how to monitor Keycloak on dynatrace

Tags: monitoring, devops, keycloak, dynatrace

I'm trying to monitor Keycloak on dynatrace, but I see only process metrics.

- is there a way to see metrics about sessions, Connected Users...
- an existing plugin for keycloak on dynatrace?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor Keycloak you will see it as a process only and not on a transaction level unfortunately.

Supported technologies can be viewed here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/supported-technologies

If there is option of collecting of extra Parameters you can always create a custom OneAgent extension. There is currently not a plugin available. You will be able to define the metrics that you would like to see in the UI: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/oneagent-extensions-tutorial

Comment: Not sure if paied comercial plugin respect stackoverflow rules, is there any one free ? opensource ?